# Using data binding for custom layout files

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am working on a project on android studio (KOTLIN) where **activity_main.xml** only contains the  drawer layout and it includes **app_bar_main.xml** file and my **app_bar_main.xml** is a coordinator layout which **includes** **main_content.xml** Now the problem is I always have to use **findViewById** to access any of the element in these layouts. I tried using **AppBarMainBinding** and **MainContentBinding** but I just can't get it working.
Even the **NavigationView**'s **headerLayout** and **menu** are not directly accessible.

Comment: one trick I found that you can use id of the include element to access elements in other layouts but I need something concrete.

Comment: Yes, if you have ids on your `include` tags it will generate nested ViewBindings as fields of your main layout. As far as flattening that hierarchy? Not built in support I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Down
Please this is my suggestion. Follow till the end

```
 First step : activity_main layout below

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

Second step : app_bar_main layout below

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_content_layout"
        layout="@layout/main_content" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

Step 3 : main_content layout below

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Android test"
        android:id="@+id/android_test"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

Now to access the TextView with id=android_test using viewBinding it should be as follow

lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

use the below to access views id.

binding.appBarLayout.mainContentLayout.androidTest.text = 
 "This works for me"

That can change the content layout
```

Comment: thanks for the descriptive answer but we actually discussed the same in the comments.